# Does iron rust because of impurities found in it (ex. carbon)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, corrosion

If we, theoretically, get a piece of ideally 100% pure iron and it is left in moist air? Will it rust? My understanding of iron rust is that the Iron itself becomes the ANODE and carbon impurities (as an example of impurities) are CATHODE, so if this cathode is not there will iron itself become anode and cathode and rust?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Three substances are required to transform iron into rust : air (oxygen), water, and a impurity at the surface of the metal. If one of these substances is missing, iron will not rust. The whole operation occurs at the contact of the impurity and iron and it has an electric origin. The reduction occurs at the impurity working as a cathode. It is well described in N. N. Greenwood and E. Earnshaw, Chemistry of the Elements, Pergamon 1983, p.1250

Comment: Carbon dioxide?

Comment: Unless you are going to show some strong citations for the need for carbon dioxide to drive rusting, I'm going to assume you just made this up as it is not mentioned in most of the summary literature on rusting.

Comment: Matt Black is right. I have checked in my library, and especially in Greenwood and Earnshaw, where electrolytic rust formation is studied in detail. Nobody mentions the role of carbon dioxide. I have done it, because I took part once upon a time to a conference where the speaker had mentioned its role. So I will delete my whole message

Answer (score 2):

**Pure iron will rust but far, far more slowly than iron with impurities**

The key point here is not whether iron will rust or not: it is about the speed of rusting.

Very pure iron will rust but very, very slowly. But even tiny impurities will promote much faster rusting. Many iron alloys (which means most iron you will ever see as very pure iron is rare) contain small amounts of carbon or other substances. On the surface of the iron these can promote tiny electrical potential that greatly speed the process of corrosion. The opposite is also true: some "stainless" alloys contain deliberately added ingredients that promote the formation of a strong, inert oxide layer on the surface that inhibits such reactions (making the substance a little like aluminium whose surface oxide layer is strong and inert, protecting a very reactive metal from oxidation reactions that would otherwise consume it quickly).

The issue with iron in general is that iron oxide is not strong and does not form a protective layer because it is flaky and friable. So, once started, rusting tends to get worse and happen faster over time.

Even pure iron will rust quickly in the wrong environment. Surface contamination will create impurity sites that can promote the electrochemical reactions that accelerate rusting. But those reactions need water, so keeping water away from the surface can slow any reactions very substantially. But, obviously, many varieties of impure iron can rust quickly when any water is present as the contaminants that promote the reactions are already present in the surface of the iron.

In summary, pure iron will rust. But slowly even when water is present. Impure iron will rust faster. All forms of iron will rust quickly if the environment adds other surface contaminants that can promote the electrochemical reactions that make rusting happen.

Answer (score -1):

It depends; sulfide inclusions will enhance oxidation. Chloride surface contamination will promote oxidation. Phosphorus inclusions will slow oxidation . Copper and chrome  "impurities" will also slow oxidation. The latter three elements are the basis of "weathering" carbon steels like Corten. The carbon affect you describe causes "graphitic corrosion" of flake type cast irons ; oxidizing the iron ,leaving carbon flakes.

Comment: I am speaking of theoretically 100% pure iron!